# Rails: "Zip::ZipError File not found"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyzip

I have this action in my `photos_controller`

```
def open_my_zip
  url = "http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Audio/Lossless_WAV_Compression/Sample_APE_File.zip"
  Zip::File.open(url) do |zipfile|
    zipfile.each do |file|
      # do something with file
      Rails.logger.debug "hi"
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, I'm getting this error

```
Zip::ZipError (File http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Audio/Lossless_WAV_Compression/Sample_APE_File.zip not found):
```

But the zip file DOES exist... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the URL directly like that. Try the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Audio/Lossless_WAV_Compression/Sample_APE_File.zip"

zipfilename = open(url)

Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfilename) do |zipfile|
end
```